# network over two routers virgin superhub

Tags: networking

i need help with networking issue.

i have virgin 100meg and a crappy virgin media super hub.

the wireless keeps dropping out.

i host a website from my main pc, so need port forward :80 to home pc.

this works fine, but i have modded my network to get rid of crappy virgin wifi.

i have a d-link dir 615 which has excellent wifi (and was designed as a cable modem - one ethernet in - 4 out, plus wifi)

i tried for days to get this configured correctly.

super hub says to use it in modem mode for this, but when i do that, all devices connected to d-link, have internet connection but my port forward doesnt work, so website goes down.

so i dont use modem mode, i just have pc plugged in super hub, and also d-link plugged into super hub.

this works fine (kinda) because the port forward works to keep website running on home pc, and d-link has excellent wifi.

but since i have done that i am having homegroup troubles.

it was fine at first, but every few days my laptop will say no homegroup computers are connected to the homegroup (and it says that on all machines, wireless and wired).

how can i get homegroup to work , over a network with two seperate routers, with one being used only for pc, and the other only used for wifi?

thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: And your programming question is? Event if this gets moved, try editing it into a better question - we don't need dramatic narrative, we need a problem desciption.

Answer (score 1):

Your D-Link is not configured to allow port 80 traffic to your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the pc with the website to the virgin box, and everything else to the d link. Then connect the d link to the virgin too.

Alternatively if the virgin box only has one ethernet, see if you can set up a port forward on the d link and virgin